# A specific directory is completely invisible to “ls” and “ls -la”, but I can "cd" into it

Tags: bash, directory, ls

This started happening out of the blue. Originally, I was able to "ls" my "Storage" folder and all 3 subdirectories were listed accordingly. ('Beta Profiles' 'OS Backups' 'Software')

Starting yesterday, "ls" now only returns, ('Beta Profiles' 'OS Backups')

As if "Software" doesn't exist anymore

I can "cd" into "Software" still and all of my files are still intact. I can only get the folder to reappear by renaming it, but once I change it back, it won't show again!

I feel like a Rootkit may be nesting in there, because this is a common symptom. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the result of `ls -ld Software`?

Comment: What Unix is this on, and what type of filesystem are the directories living on?  Rootkits seldom nest in random subdirectories in users' home directories. Where are these directories located?

Comment: most obvious but you never know: is `ls` an alias? `alias ls`? does `echo *` show that directory?

Comment: @RomeoNinov the output of that command is this: “drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4096 Nov 26 15:24 Software”

Comment: @Kusalananda Ubuntu. The drive is formatted ext4, but ecryptfs is used on that specific folder. This is an External drive mounted to /media/Storage

Comment: @mosvy Yeah. I unaliased everything just in case. And echo * also missed the folder. It’s very weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by experimentation. Nothing else was working, so I decided to rebuild my eCryptfs folder. This new folder uses the same name as the last one and uses the same encryption key. No idea why that last folder glitched out, but I think it was definitely related to eCryptfs, as it is working normally again

Answer (score 1):

It is by chance that "Storage" folder mounted through SMB/cifs? If you don't know you can check it in "/etc/fstab" file or typing the command "mount | grep cifs". 
If that is the case, you could try the "vers=1.0" option while mounting the FS (less secure), or if you have access to the server, modifying the share and mounting it through NFS.

Comment: Well, the machine connects to the drive through USB 3.0, and uses Ecryptfs for encryption. BUT, the machine does host this drive as a Samba share. This machine is mainly an SMB server, so maybe Samba has done something weird

Comment: I think you are right, it seems a Samba issue (maybe only with some clients). I fixed similar problems in the past (random disappearing folders/files) by forcing an older cifs version in clients, but this is an insecure option and vulnerable to exploits.

Comment: Yeah the folder isn’t appearing in the Samba share. I tried on macOS Windows and now Linux. No dice. Is there anything I can do to fix this or is the folder just screwed?

Comment: Maybe the output of “dmesg” will contain some useful info about the problem. You could try mounting the share on a client and then executing “dmesg” or “dmesg —ctime”.

Comment: Output was too long to paste here, so here's a link to it (its hosted on my server, pardon the domain) https://tdserver.ddns.net:65403/output.txt. That was with Kali Linux

Comment: As I can see in the last two lines, it seems that mount is auto selecting SMB3 as default dialect and, for some reason, that dialect is not working properly. For my research in this topic I currently only know two ways for "fixing" it.
1. Use NFS instead of cifs (best way but it could be difficult for some Windows clients to connect the share).
2. Use cifs 1.0 (insecure). You can pass the option "vers=1.0" while mounting the share on clients.
I'm sorry that I can't help you more than this.

Comment: Thanks man... I think it’s EcryptFS. I have filename crypto enabled and I think it’s messing with the FS. Not only does the name “Software” not show up, but other random ones like “Installers” and “Programs”. Not sure why. I might have to decrypt, start a new folder with a new Key, move the data over, and re-encrypt. I’ll report if this works in the morning. (I mean, I sure hope this works. It’s the last resort, and a pain in the ass too)